# every irreducible polynomial has a root in a field extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

In the following proof I’m finding it hard to understand why $\pi (x)$ is a root of $p(x)$. When $p$ is evaluated with $\pi (x)$ it gives the ZERO COSET and not zero itself. So how is this a root?

There are similar questions on this site but none of them explain this exact part.

---

Let $F$ be a field and $p(x)$ an irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$. Then we can find a field extension $L$ of $F$ such that $p(x)$ has a root in $L$.

Proof: Clearly the ideal $<p(X)>$ generated by $p(x)$ is maximal in $F[x]$. So $F[x]/<p(x)>$ is a field. Let us denote it by $L$. So $L$ is a field extension of $F$ since we have $F \hookrightarrow F[x] \xrightarrow{\rm \pi} L$ in a natural way.

$p(\pi (x))=p(x + <p(x)>) = \sum_{i = 0}^n a_i(x + <p(x)>)^i = \sum_{i = 0}^n a_ix^i + <p(x)> = p(x) + <p(x)> = 0 + <p(x)>$

Comment: $F$ is included (identified with the image) in $F[x]/(p(x))$ as the elements $a+(p(x))$, for $a\in F$. So, the zero coset is the new $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\pi$ is a ring homomorphism from $F[x]$ to $L$, we have
$$p\bigl(\pi(x)\bigr)=\pi\bigl(p(x)\bigr)=p(x)+\langle\,p(x)\,\rangle=\langle\,p(x)\,\rangle. $$

Comment: Yes but how does that mean pi(x) is a root of p(x)?

Comment: Simply because it means that in the quotient ring, $p\bigl(\pi(x)\bigr)=0$.

Comment: But p(x) doesn’t actually belong to the $L$,the quotient ring. Because p(x) is a polynomial not a coset.

Comment: $p(x)+\langle\,p(x)\,\rangle$  *is* a coset. The root is $\pi(x)=x+\langle\,p(x)\,\rangle$, another coset.

Comment: Ok but we are not substituting pi(x) into the coset but instead the polynomial, which doesn’t below to the quotient ring???

Comment: We  substitute the coset $\pi(x)$ to $x$ in the polynomial and obtain the coset of $0$.

Comment: But this is the coset of 0 and not 0 itself. So how can it be a root?

Comment: The elements of the field $L$ are cosets (mod. $p(x)$). Think of one of the constructions of $\mathbf C$, starting from $\mathbf R$: it is defined as the quotient field $\mathbf R[X]/\langle\,X^2+1\,\rangle$, and the imaginary unit $i$ is simply the coset $X\bmod X^2+1$.

Comment: So the zero in the field extension has changed to the zero coset?

Comment: Since the set of cosets is a field…